# Why unicode character \u0004 is not showing in Javafx TextArea

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have algorithm which converts given **unicode string** to some other form. User has to provide this **unicode string** via `TextArea`. This unicode string contains 
[image] (\u0004) character which will process by algorithm;

Example string : [image]

But the problem is that the string [image] is converted to `aaa` when pasted to TextArea in javafx. See image below

[image]

That was not a problem when I used .Net framework. `TextArea` of .Net Framework shows it correctly as you can see in the image below
[image]

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: consider doing `String fixedString = Normalizer.normalize(problemString, Normalizer.Form.NFC);` then use the `fixedString` in the text area. [this is the `Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class

Comment: Unicode U+0000 to U+001F and U+007F to U+009F are control characters and not graphics. On _Windows_ some of them are treated as graphics _sometimes_, though not always the same graphics; on other systems never TTBOMK. And Java was designed to support multiple platforms not just Windows.

Comment: @user1 I tried `Normalizer` it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked where the replacement actually happens. It's in the `TextArea.TextAreaContent` class which unfortunately cannot be replaced with a custom implementation since it's is passed for every single constructor of `TextArea` (at least not without reflection or a custom classloader).

You could apply a workaround though by replacing the text with text that renders properly in a `TextFormatter` though. If you need to keep track of the "real" text you could also use the `TextFormatter` to log the changes and override `TextArea`'s `copy` method to copy the appropriate content to the clipboard.

```
textArea.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {
    String text = change.getText();
    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
        change.setText(text.replace('\u0004', '\u02e9')); // replace eot char with "valid" one
    }
    return change;
}));
```

Note that JavaFX also removes all other characters < `0x20` that do not recieve special handling.

Comment: It would be a problem when the character i am replacing with is already in the input string

Answer (score 0):

This will not resolve your problem but it may help you to diagnose the issue and may be resolve it. I wrote an Open Source libary called MgntUtils that has several utilities. Ome of them is converting any String to Unicode sequences and vise-versa. For instance you can do

```
StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello World")
```

And get "\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064" as result. Method 
`StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(
"\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064");`

Would do the reverse operation. What you can do is to copy your String from your text area and convert it to unicodes. Then you can see if it contains your unicodes in question and just doesn't display them or they are not contained n the String (i.e. were filtered out). This may give you a good start. Here is the link to the article that explains about the MgntUtils library and where to get it (as maven artifact or at github) in both cases it comes with source code and java doc. Look for the paragraph called "String Unicode converter". [MgntUtils](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)

Comment: I ran a small test. Using my Utility I replaced letter 'H' in word "Hello" with unicode '\u004' Here was ny output:  
"Hello - ello"    
So it seems that Java consideres this symbol not displayable. I bet that if you decode your String from TextArea you will see that your codes are there and simply not displayed

Comment: When i paste the string shown in question (five characters) to text area and then copy it again from the text area and paste it some where else (even in eclipse), then string length gets reduce to 3 (only `aaa` is left), which means `\u0004` gets vanish from the original string. I tried [fabian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian) answer and it actually worked